# Simple Google Spreadsheet Script to copy and paste cells gives error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some relatively simple code below that throws an error: : "Cannot convert NaN to (class)".

All I want to do is copy some cells from one place to another!

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong with this code?

Many thanks in advance.

```
function myFunction() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet 1');   
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()  

  for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row )
    if (values[row][5] == 'Here')
     var maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows()
     var startRow = (row)+1
     var numRows = (maxRows)-(row)
     var Range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 3, numRows, 3).getValues()
     sheet.getRange(row, 3, numRows, 3).setValues(Range)     // (row, column, numRows, numColumns)      
  }
```

So as the code hopefully shows, I want to copy cells in the range C:E but only rows x to getMaxRows(), where x is the row number where 'Here' is found in column F, plus 1. Then I want to paste this into the same columns C:E but one row higher than originally (into the same row as 'Here' in column F).

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks for looking.

EDIT: The error is on this line :

```
var Range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 3, numRows, 3).getValues()
```

In my sheet, the cells to be copied could countain blank cells and even entire blank rows. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Did you mean to have `newRange` in there? because that variable is never defined. Also, does it give you a line number that is throwing that error?

Comment: Hi again Phil. Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question to remove that undefined variable. The error still shows, and therefore the question still stands! I've also added which line the error appears. Many thanks, vin

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your description instead of your code (why don't you use {} in loops and conditions ?) I suggest you try this

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet 1');   
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()  
  var maxRows = sheet.getLastRow()
  var datatoCopy = []   
  for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row ){
    if (values[row][5] == 'here'){
     var whereToCopy = row+1
     Logger.log(whereToCopy);
     break
     }
     }
   for(row=whereToCopy-1;row<maxRows;++row){
    datatoCopy.push([values[row][2]+'**']);// store column data in an array - remove the ** that I used to see what was copied ;-)
    }
    Logger.log(datatoCopy)
sheet.getRange(whereToCopy, 5, datatoCopy.length, 1).setValues(datatoCopy);// overwrite data to column E
}
```

Following your comment, try this version ?

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet 1');   
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()  
  var maxRows = sheet.getLastRow()
  var datatoCopy = []   
  for( var row = values.length -1; row >= 0; --row ){
    if (values[row][5] == 'here'){
     var whereToCopy = row
     Logger.log(whereToCopy);
     break
     }
     }
   for(row=whereToCopy-1;row<maxRows-1;++row){
    var rowData=[]
    rowData.push(values[row+1][2]+'*C*');// I added these 'indicators' to show what happens... delete them when the result is ok ;-)
    rowData.push(values[row+1][3]+'*D*');//
    rowData.push(values[row+1][4]+'*E*');//
    datatoCopy.push(rowData);// store column data in an array - remove the ** that I used to see what was copied ;-)
    }
    Logger.log(datatoCopy)
sheet.getRange(whereToCopy, 3, datatoCopy.length, datatoCopy[0].length).setValues(datatoCopy);// overwrite data to column E
}
```

Comment: Hi there Serge, thank you for your answer. I actually want to copy a 3-column range C:E, and paste it in the same columns C:E, but one row higher than originally. I have edited my question to make it clearer. Does your code need much editing to acheive this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I created a test sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dHY5alNSb0h3aFMwWkVtTk9iT1ktbnc&usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi Serge, thank you again, your answers are very much appreciated. The script works great when I run it the first time but when I run it a second or third time it pushes the data up beyond the cell 'Here' in column F. Any ideas how I can stop this from happening? Regards

Comment: Hi Serge. I've been thinking that maybe the variables in the script need to be 'cleared' at the end. Would that make the script run normally the second or third time it is run? If so, any ideas how to do that? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, I've tested [on this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dHY5alNSb0h3aFMwWkVtTk9iT1ktbnc&usp=sharing) and I can't reproduce the issue you describe... could you try it please ? and tell me what happens via the document mail. thx

Comment: Hello again. Thanks for getting back to me. I've tried the new sheet but it now it produces the issue the first time I run the script! This is strange, I've checked the code and it's exactly the same as the first test sheet. I ran the first test sheet's script and it still works fine the first time but not after that. It's very wierd.  I have left the new test sheet after running the script once so you can see the result! Sorry I don't quite know what you meant about the 'document mail', do you mean to communicate via the comments in the actual spreadsheet? Regards

Comment: Forgot to say, this may reproduce the issue: If you run the script several times, and move the 'here' into a different cell in column F, after each time, the issue might be reproduced at your end. Thanks, I'm ever so grateful for your help so far.

Comment: Hello Serge. I managed to get the script working every time by removing the second loop. I've added it (& 'Sheet2') to the latest test spreadsheet. I used getMaxRows() instead of getLastRows() as my sheet will look more like Sheet2 (no 'completely blank' rows but some rows C:E may be blank so I thought getMaxRows() would be better for my case). I wouldn't want you to spend anymore time as you have helped me so much already, however could you please tell me if there's any reason I shouldn't use this 'working' code, or if I should modify it for some reason? Many thanks Serge!